# Explication of one line in Objective-C Manual

Tags: objective-c

I view the next line in the Apple manual and I don't understanding

```
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

The complete code is

```
NSDate *startDate = ...;
NSDate *endDate = ...;

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                 initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                          fromDate:startDate
                                          toDate:endDate options:0];
NSInteger months = [components month];
NSInteger days = [components day];
```

What does the | I know this charter for the OR operator !

In my logical unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit OR NSDayCalendarUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and C-like/derived languages often use something called a bitfield to pass various combinations of flags to functions. Some integer is considered a bitfield, and each bit in the integer represents the boolean value of some flag. For example, if we had a 1 byte bitfield, it might look this:

```
10010101
```

That means that whatever flags are defined to be bit positions 0, 2, 4, 7 are set to `true`, and the others to `false`. Instead of making you construct this bitfield manually and remembering which bit is which flag, you usually construct it using bitwise operations and predefined constants.

In your case, `NSMonthCalendarUnit` is defined to be `01000`, and `NSDayCalendarUnit` is defined to be `10000`. When you **bitwise OR** (`|`) them together, you get `11000`, the bitfield representing having both of those flags set.

Comment: 0, **2**, **4**, and 7 are set to true in your example.

Comment: @KenThomases: Whoops -- fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @Linuxios Thanks The last question in kCFCalendarUnitQuarter = (1UL << 11) the UL what is? Is Unsigned Long?

Comment: @user3741098: I think so. Not totally sure though.